# How can I improvise sunglasses?

Tags: substitute-tool, eyeglasses, eyesight

Where I live it's usually cloudy and rainy during the winter, so I rarely have my sunglasses with me.  But when the sun does come out after it's been raining (we call this a "sun-break") the glare of the sun against the wet pavement is blinding.

How can I improvise a pair of sunglasses?  Wearing a cap or squinting doesn't work.

Comment: I would advise caution here. Well made sunglasses have UV filtering on them. Reducing the light getting to your eyes will cause your pupils to expand, so poorly executed light filters for your eyes can cause a UV ridk to your eyes

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Two ways of improvising sunglasses**

**1. Make Slit Sunglasses**

Slit sunglasses work by limiting the upper and lower angles of light coming into your eyes.

To improvise these glasses you can use the cover of a paperback book, plastic cards or some other stiff but bendable material. Make the slits with a penknife. The nose and earpieces can be constructed of string, rubber bands, twist ties or the material itself.

[image]

**2. Make Pinhole Sunglasses**

[Pinhole sunglasses](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pinhole_glasses) work by limiting the total amount of light that come to your eyes. However, due to the pinhole effect you still have a full field of vision, although you may have some visual artifacts where the two visual fields meet.  Pinhole glasses also have the advantage of correcting your vision, also thanks to the pinhole effect.

You can make pinhole glasses out of the same material as slit sunglasses and use a safety pin or bit of stiff wire to make the holes.

[image]

Comment: These greatly reduce visibility, and you shouldn't use them while biking.

Comment: @J.Musser I disagree. I wore prescription pinhole "glasses" for a few months to increase my eyesight (they require your eyes to refocus very often so you train your eye muscles with them). They where darkening the light significantly, but I had no problem with side visibility, at least not more then with regular sunglasses.